# How to set cursor to after last character in vim?

Tags: linux, vim, keyboard-shortcuts

Why can't I insert at the end of a line in vim if there's no whitespace at the end? Let's take for example my SSH config file:

[image]

I try to use <kbd>$</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>, but I can't seem to get to the end of the word. When I start typing in `insert` mode, I get the following:

[image]

What gives? How do I make sure I can insert at the **very** end of a line?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

What you want is to use is the <kbd>a</kbd> command instead of the <kbd>i</kbd> command to enter insert mode.  Or if you want to jump to the end of the line and start insert mode, use <kbd>A</kbd>.  Note that <kbd>I</kbd> will jump to the beginning of the line and enter insert mode.

Comment: Works, thanks. Note that I didn't put `I`, but `l`, which look the same :/

Comment: I did see that, but it was clear from context that you were trying to position the cursor for the `i` command, so I responded accordingly.

Answer (score 11):

You can also put `set ve+=onemore` into your `.vimrc`; that'll let you put the cursor onto the "empty" space at the end of every line. 
Note that <kbd>$</kbd> will still put you on the last character;
you'll need to use something like <kbd>$</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> (lowercase "L"), 
<kbd>/</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> or 
<kbd>9</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>|</kbd> (vertical bar).

Comment: `noremap $ $l` seems like a reasonable addition to .vimrc to me :)

Comment: In addition to what Samy stated: by default, if the `virtualedit` option is set to `onemore` you can use `g$` to put the cursor onto the "empty" space at the end of any line. That is, there is no need to map the `$` key to `$l`.